# Python import html 'No Tables Found'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to scrape a table in an url and I'm doing exactly the same steps I done to scrape successfully in another url. But this time I got the `ValueError: No tables found` error.

I'm using the Colab environment

Following is the code that results in the error above:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/busca-avancada'
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"  
 }

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(r.text,  decimal=',', thousands='.')[0]
```

Comment: How do you know there *are* any tables at this URL?

Comment: different pages may need different steps. And first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add table to page. `requests`, `pandas` can't run JavaScript. You can also first check what you get in `r.text` maybe there is some warning for bots/scripts/spamers/hackers or Captcha which tries block you.

Comment: did you check HTML on this page ? It **doesn't** use `<table>` to display elements. You will have to write code to get elements. But it uses JavaScript so you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.